# Userform not inserting numbers to my excel table

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I've been trying to get this to work all day and I'm not sure why it won't.  Relatively new to VBA so I apologize if my code is terrible.  Everything else fills correctly, but I can't get the numbers to populate on click like everything else.  I've tried formatting the cells to numbers as well and that did nothing.  Here is my code, the numbers should go into column 4.

```
 Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()
Dim Row As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("All Birthdays and Anniversaries")

iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

If Trim(Me.EmpName.Value) = "" Then
    Me.EmpName.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please enter employee name!"
    Exit Sub
End If
    
If Trim(Me.HDate.Value) = "" Then
    Me.HDate.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please enter hire date!"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.cboMonth.Value) = "" Then
    Me.cboMonth.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please enter birth month!"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.cboDay.Value) = "" Then
    Me.cboDay.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please enter birth day!"
    Exit Sub
End If

With ws
    .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.EmpName.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.HDate.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.cboMonth.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = cboDay.Value
End With

Me.EmpName.Value = ""
Me.HDate.Value = ""
Me.cboMonth.Value = ""
Me.cboDay.Value = ""


End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
cboMonth.List = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
cboDay.List = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31")
cboDay.AddItem "1"

End Sub
```

Comment: I just did a test by quickly making a form with this code and works fine. I would however, recommend finding the last row via `iRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1` as you can get errors from using the Find command whereas you won't by counting the rows. The only thing is you need a specific column. Anyway though when you say the numbers, do you mean the day value won't enter into column D of your sheet? Also what is the purpose of adding a second "1" to the day list? You then have two "1" values there.

Comment: Whenever I submit the form nothing populates in column D.  I thought it was an issue of it being a numerical value and not a text value but that wasn't it.  The extra one was me trying different ways to try to get it to work. I'm definitely going to try the method you suggested for finding the last row.  However I still have the issue of the number not populating.

Comment: I can send you my sheet so you can see what I'm talking about if that would help?

Comment: I noticed that when I told it to go into column 5 it worked, for whatever reason it refuses to put it into column 4

Comment: It's not protected or anything is it? You could maybe try deleting column 4 and inserting a new one.

Comment: It is a protected sheet, but I'm not sure why it would enter all the other data and not the column 4 data

Comment: What's the font colour in column 4?

Comment: There is formatting in the table that converts all the text to white and changes the fill color based on the month. Again Everything else shows correctly. Stand by let me show you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to attach my sheet here.

Comment: If you want to share your file you need to upload it to a reputable file hosting site and paste the link to it here. You can't upload files directly to this site.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AklaeRzu8812gs0zWViP2aWaJsCB4Q?e=w8qKew

Comment: You've changed it from the original posted code.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was fiddling around with it.  There isn't many changes for the specific code I posted though.

Comment: Yes as per the answer below, it's your worksheet_change event causing the problems. Your easiest method is to simply just call the sub after you add the new row to update the rows instead of looking for a change event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the sorting that's triggered every time you enter a value on the sheet 'All Birthdays and Anniversaries.

You need to stop the code being executed and you can do that by disabling events while you are adding data from the userform to the sheet.

If you do want the sort to run after you've entered the data on the sheet you could simply call it after you've entered all the data on the sheet.

```vb
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    With ws
        .Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.EmpName.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.HDate.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.cboMonth.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.Day.Value
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    ' optional
    Call Sheet3.SortInTable
```

Comment: Oh. My. Goodness.  I didn't even think about that.  Thank you soooooo so much.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: @Norie You published while I was still typing. Well done! But will the sort not trigger the Change event if it's carried out with events enabled?

Comment: Good point, not something I considered initially. Strangely enough though, calling SortInTable after the data from the userform has been added to the worksheet doesn't trigger the Change event.

Answer (score 0):

Your code write the day perfectly. But then the Change event deletes it. This is the cure:-

1. Add `Application.EnableEvents = False` before starting to write to the sheet.
2. Move your Sub `SortInTable` to a standard code module.
3. Add a call of `SortInTable` after writing to column 4
4. Add `Application.EnableEvents = True`  below this procedure call.